# Product of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Please, for the two lists:

```
L1 := {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}} 
L2 := {{g, h, i}, {j, k, q}}
```

I need the result

```
{{{a g, a h, a i}, {c g, c h, c i}, {e g, e h, e i}}, 
 {{b j, b k, b q}, {d j, d k, d q}, {f j, f k, f q}}}
```

Comment: Look up `Outer[]` and `MapThread[]`.

Comment: I tried, i think there is  additional some thing with any of them

Comment: `Outer` provide more terms than this result and `MapThread ` provide less one.

Answer (score 14):

Also

```
Transpose @@ Outer[Times, {L2}, L1, 1]

Transpose[# L2 & /@ L1]
```

Comment: Last one is pretty, +1

Answer (score 13):

```
MapThread[Outer[Times, #, #2] &, {L1\[Transpose], L2}]
```

Or simpler:

```
MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {L1\[Transpose], L2}]
```

Comment: Many thanks for you, it works.

Comment: @Ali if this worked for you consider accepting the answer. Benefits the answerer and also indicates to people that the question has been answered sufficiently well.

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
KroneckerProduct @@@ Transpose@{Transpose@L1, L2}
Outer[Times, ##] & @@@ Transpose@{Transpose@L1, L2}
```

> {{{a g, a h, a i}, {c g, c h, c i}, {e g, e h, e i}}, {{b j, b k, 
>      b q}, {d j, d k, d q}, {f j, f k, f q}}}